# Javascript methods with a var in it

Tags: javascript, object, methods, var

I'm trying to get the value of an object in a object but the key value is a variable so I don't know how to have this code working:

```
var res = 'Hello';
var greetings = {
  'Hello': {'lang':'EN' ,'goodbye': 'Goodbye'},
  'Bonjour': {'lang':'FR', 'goodbye': 'Aurevoir'}
}
```

Later I want to use this :

```
greetings.res.lang
```

to get : 'EN', for now I get 'undefined' because it evaluates the expression greetings.res and not greeting.Hello so it doesn't find it in the list.

EDIT : Thanks for the quick answer guys !

Comment: `greetings[res].lang`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev there was an error when it posted...later it edited the posted one was `var greetings = {
  'Hello': {'lang':'EN' ,'goodbye': 'Goodbye'},
  'Bonjour': {'lang:'FR', 'goodbye': 'Aurevoir'}
}`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah.when i checked, the JSON was not fine that's why i commented like that

Comment: @SergioTulentsev removed. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [How to create a Dictionary with Key/Value pairs](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2015/09/05/JavaScript-Basics-How-to-create-a-Dictionary-with-KeyValue-pairs)

```js
var res = 'Hello';
var greetings = {
  'Hello': {'lang':'EN' ,'goodbye': 'Goodbye'},
  'Bonjour': {'lang':'FR', 'goodbye': 'Aurevoir'}
}

console.log(greetings[res].lang);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
var res = 'Hello';
var greetings = {
  'Hello': {'lang':'EN' ,'goodbye': 'Goodbye'},
  'Bonjour': {'lang': 'FR', 'goodbye': 'Aurevoir'}
}

alert(greetings[res].lang);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[]` when you have dynamic keys:

```
greetings[res].lang
```

OR

```
greetings[res]['lang']
```

Answer (score -2):

You can access it like this:

```
greetings[res].lang
```